# Measuring ancillas in Shor's algorithm

Tags: measurement, shors-algorithm

When considering Shor's algorithm, we use ancilla qubits to effectively obtain the state
$$\sum_x \left|x,f(x)\right>$$
for the function $f(x) = a^x \mod N$.

As I have learned it, we then measure the ancilla qubits, to obtain, say $f(x) = b$ and get the state
$$\sum_{x\mid f(x) = b} \left|x,f(x)\right>.$$

Then applying a QFT will give the period. However, I think that the measurement of the ancilla qubits is not necessary, in order to be able to apply the QFT (or its inverse for that matter) and do a measurement to obtain the period.

Is that correct? Is it necessary to measure the ancilla qubits in Shor's algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is that correct? Is it [not] necessary to measure the ancilla qubits in Shor's algorithm?

Correct, it is not necessary to measure the ancillae.

This is easily seen by appealing to the no-communication theorem. If measuring the ancillae could affect the success of the algorithm, you could communicate faster-than-light by starting the algorithm many times, giving the ancillae to Alice, sending her far away, have her encode a bit by measuring or not measuring the ancillae, then having Bob measure how often the factoring was succeeding to read out the bit.

Another way to see that this works [is by simulating it](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setR%22%2C%22arg%22%3A27%7D%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setB%22%2C%22arg%22%3A8%7D%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Density7%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22inputA7%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22*BToAmodR5%22%5D%2C%5B%22Density7%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22QFT%E2%80%A07%22%5D%2C%5B%22Density7%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22Chance7%22%5D%5D%7D). From the results you can see that, as soon as the modular-exponentiation into the ancillae has happened, the density matrix of the input has been decohered in a very particular periodic way. And that the inverse QFT of this decohered density matrix has magnitude spikes at the correct places:

[image]

Notice that this is all in place even though the ancillae were not measured. Measuring them changes none of the density matrices.